# serve specific git branch

Tags: git

I'm setting up a QA environment for a project that consists of (at the moment) purely static files.  I want QA to be able to test specific versions that we flag as "ready for testing".

My idea is that I want to be able to serve any git branch from a qa site, probably via URIs like:

`381dc1a.qa.somesite.com` where `381dc1a` references the git uid.

The only way I know of to do this is to proxy all of the files through `git show`, which isn't much of an issue considering the very, very light load on QA sites, but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea.

What I want to avoid is having 200 different directories each with its own checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting up a post-receive hook that uses `git archive` to archive each desired revision, as it comes in, to a directory on your disk, then use an ordinary webserver to serve those files.

For un-compressed directories:

```
git archive SOMEREF | tar -xC /path/to/folder/revision
```

For tarballs:

```
git archive SOMEREF > /path/to/folder/revision.tar
```

For zip files:

```
git archive --format=zip SOMEREF > /path/to/folder/revision.zip
```

---

Since you said you didn't want a bunch of directories, though...

Your other alternative would to be to write a small app that runs `git archive` on demand (if you didn't want to proactively export revisions before someone requested them).